# Form A to Monitor, Form B to secondary output

Tags: c#, forms, multiple-monitors

I have an application that I am writing in C#.  The application has two forms, call them Form A and Form B.  I want to display Form A on the monitor, while Form B is being displayed on a secondary output (such as a TV screen).  Does anyone have any idea what I need to do to setup Form B to display to the secondary output?  Do I need to do anything at the Application level?

Thanks,

Doug

Comment: Can't you just click and drag it over?

Comment: [Similar Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561104/how-do-i-ensure-a-form-displays-on-the-additional-monitor-in-a-dual-monitor-sc)

Answer (score 2):

[Enumerate the set of monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538602/find-number-and-resolution-to-all-monitors) to find the size and offset of each within the virtual screen space. Then move your forms to the appropriate coordinates.